# How to update kdb table transversely

Tags: kdb

I have these two tables:

```
tab:([]col1:`abc`def`ghe`abc;val_00:`a`b`c`e;val_01:`d`e`f`t;val_02:`g`h`e`g;val_03:`r`t`y`o)
tab2:([]col1:`abc`abc`abc`abc`def`def`def`ghe`ghe`ghe;col2:0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9;col3:`Ashley`Peter`John`Molly`Apple`Orange`Banana`Robin`Tony`Bob)
```

and this is the result I am looking for:

```
tabResult:([]col1:`abc`def`ghe`abc;val_00:`Ashley`b`c`Ashley;val_01:`Peter`e`f`Peter;val_02:`John`h`e`John;val_03:`Molly`t`y`Molly)

    col1    val_00  val_01  val_02  val_03
    abc     Ashley  Peter   John    Molly
    def     b       e        h      t
    ghe     c       f        e      y
    abc     Ashley  Peter   John    Molly
```

I would like to update `tab` depending on `tab2`. If `` col1=`abc,col2=1 `` in `tab2`, I would like to update `val_01` to `` `Peter `` in `tab`, and if `` col1 =`abc,col2=2 `` in `tab2`, I would like to update `val_02` field with `` `John `` in `tab` etc.

This is what I have so far:

```
{![tab;enlist(=;`col1;enlist x);0b;(enlist y)!enlist z]} . (`abc;`val_01;)
```

The function above works if the field is numerical and I use a number as the last arg. However, I am not sure how to update symbols and how to generalise this function for all tables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I'm understanding your request correctly, you're trying to update a field that has a long type with values that are of symbol type. This is going to fail with a `'type` error as column values are expected to be uniform in type. What you can alternatively do is create new columns for the symbol entries, and after that select the columns you want.

Is something like this what you had in mind? I've assumed that the column name is determined by its `col2` value in `tab`. Also it looks like you have two `val_01` columns in your `tab` input, I assumed one of these was supposed to be `val_02`.

```
q)(uj/){![tab;enlist(=;`col1;enlist x);0b;(enlist`$"val_0",string[y],"_sym")!enlist enlist z]}.'flip tab2`col1`col2`col3
col1 val_00 val_01 val_02 val_03 val_01_sym val_02_sym val_03_sym val_04_sym val_05_sym val_06_sym val_07_sym val_08_sym val_09_sym
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
abc  1      2      2      3      Peter
def  2      2      3      2
ghe  3      3      1      1
abc  1      2      2      3                 John
def  2      2      3      2
ghe  3      3      1      1
abc  1      2      2      3                            Molly
def  2      2      3      2
ghe  3      3      1      1
abc  1      2      2      3
def  2      2      3      2                                       Apple
ghe  3      3      1      1
abc  1      2      2      3
def  2      2      3      2                                                  Orange
ghe  3      3      1      1
abc  1      2      2      3
def  2      2      3      2                                                             Banana
ghe  3      3      1      1
abc  1      2      2      3
def  2      2      3      2
ghe  3      3      1      1                                                                        Robin
abc  1      2      2      3
def  2      2      3      2
ghe  3      3      1      1                                                                                   Tony
abc  1      2      2      3
def  2      2      3      2
ghe  3      3      1      1                                                                                              Bob
```

**EDIT:**

Based on your comments, I've amended my solution:

```
q)cols[tab]#{![x;enlist(=;`col1;enlist y`col1);0b;(enlist`$"val_0",string y`col2)!enlist enlist y`col3]}/[tab;tab2]
col1 val_00 val_01 val_02 val_03
--------------------------------
abc  Ashley Peter  John   Molly
def  b      e      h      t
ghe  c      f      e      y
abc  Ashley Peter  John   Molly
```

Comment: Thanks Cathal, Ijust updated my first tab.  so the joined table I am looking for is `Peter will replace all values in val_01 when col1=`abc.  and `John will replace all values in val_02 when col1=  `abc

Comment: I don't understand the ask here, is the `col2` value no longer relevant?

Comment: i updated my sample table and posted a desired result I am looking for. can you kindly take a look please? =)

Comment: the number of col2 in tab2 determine the fields of tab that will be replaced.  For example, number is 2 in col2 in tab2, will replace the value of val_02 in tab 1 depending on col1.  and 3 in col2 is for val_03 field

Comment: Added an edit to my original post.

Comment: thanks, your answer is pretty good!! however, my actual tables are more complicated. its pretty stranger, i keep getting length error and cannot figure out why.

Comment: ``{![x;enlist(=;`col1;enlist y`col1);0b;(enlist`$"val_0",string y`col2)!enlist enlist y`col3]}/[tab;tab2]`` does this work? (I've taken the `cols[tab]#` out of my solution.)

Comment: yeah i kept playing around. i think when the table is 1#tab it works and when its more than 1, like 2#tab, it wouldn't work even the 2 records have the same values of col1.  it keeps giving me length error

Comment: i removed "enlist" from y`col1 and it works. not very sure the theory behind it.

Comment: What is the type of `col1`? You can check using `meta tab`.

Comment: both symbol and has parted attribute

Comment: Is it capital S or lowercase s?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241905/discussion-between-cathal-oneill-and-terry).